# what to recast as an NSSplitViewItem

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am trying to self-learn OSX application development so I can make up all of my own bad habits 8).

---

**Probably extraneous information**

I have a trial app that works successfully - it resizes itself based on input from the user via a slider.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The key piece of code that does this is in one View controller ...

```
class JunkViewController2: NSViewController {

    var myY: CGFloat!

    @IBOutlet weak var mySlider: NSSlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: NSView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(self.view.frame.width, 83)
    }

    @IBAction func mySlider(sender: NSSlider) {

        let mySplitViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! JunkSplitViewController

        switch mySlider.intValue {
        case 3:
            myY = 140.0
            mySplitViewController.splitViewItems[2].collapsed = false
            mySplitViewController.splitViewItems[1].collapsed = false
            mySplitViewController.showSubview(2)
            mySplitViewController.showSubview(1)
            mySplitViewController.showSubview(0)
        case 2:
            myY = 110.0
            mySplitViewController.splitViewItems[2].collapsed = true
            mySplitViewController.splitViewItems[1].collapsed = false
            mySplitViewController.hideSubview(2)
            mySplitViewController.showSubview(1)
            mySplitViewController.showSubview(0)
        default:
            myY = 80.0
            mySplitViewController.splitViewItems[2].collapsed = true
            mySplitViewController.splitViewItems[1].collapsed = true
            mySplitViewController.hideSubview(2)
            mySplitViewController.hideSubview(1)
            mySplitViewController.showSubview(0)
        }

        mySplitViewController.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(self.view.frame.width, myY - 50 + 3)
        self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(self.view.frame.width, myY + 3)

    }

}
```

---

**More pertinent information**

In what is working, above, on the story board I have three duplicate ViewControllers connected to a SplitView controller. I do a bunch of what feels like belts and suspenders work to make sure that everything gets resized properly - but the key part (I think) is the `.collapsed` property.

I am now trying to accomplish the same thing, using a completely different method - dynamically adding / removing split view items. This should allow me to have only one of the small ViewControllers on my story board, and then instantiate it as needed.

Following that idea, here is my SplitViewController ...

```
class JunkSplitViewController: NSSplitViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mySplitView: NSSplitView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        //mySplitView.adjustSubviews()
    }

    func makeChild() -> SmallViewController {
        let mySmallGroup = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("smallVwCtl")
        self.addSplitViewItem(mySmallGroup as! NSSplitViewItem)
        return mySmallGroup as! SmallViewController
    }

}
```

The main view controller invokes the `makeChild` function.

```
class JunkViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mySlider: NSSlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var myView: NSView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        self.preferredContentSize = NSMakeSize(self.view.frame.width, 83)
    }

    @IBAction func mySlider(sender: NSSlider) {

        let mySplitViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! JunkSplitViewController

        while mySlider.intValue.toIntMax() > mySplitViewController.splitViewItems.count.toIntMax() {
            mySplitViewController.makeChild()
        }

        while mySlider.intValue.toIntMax() < mySplitViewController.splitViewItems.count.toIntMax(){
            mySplitViewController.splitViewItems.removeLast()
        }

    }

}
```

I get an error at the `self.addSplitViewItem(mySmallGroup as! NSSplitViewItem)` line of JunkSplitViewController ... "Could not cast value of type Scratch2.SmallViewController to NSSplitViewItem"

I've tried a handful of combinations (forcing mySmallGroup, 'self.addSplitViewItem(mySmallGroup as! SmallViewController)`, etc.) Everything leads to a similar error, either at compile or run time.

I cannot find any documentation on SplitViewItem.

So the question - what will work as input to addSplitViewItem and still successfully connect a new instance of SmallViewController?

And gratefully accept any comments/feedback on the methodology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate it when I find my answer minutes after posting  a question ...

Based on info I found [here](http://www.brandpending.com/blog/2015/9/24/inserting-and-replacing-split-view-items-with-swift-and-storyboards) ...

```
func makeChild() -> SmallViewController {
    let mySmallGroup = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("smallVwCtl") as! SmallViewController
    self.addSplitViewItem(NSSplitViewItem(viewController: mySmallGroup))
    return mySmallGroup
}
```

... but I'd still like to hear any feedback on methodology. Thanks.